# O Texto do banco de dados não aparece no TDBMemo

Tags: delphi-10, delphi-berlin

Tenho uma tabela que uma das colunas é ligada a um `TDBMemo` só que os texto que está na tabela não aparece no `TDBMemo` quando a tabela está aberta, tanto em modo de Execução como no de Design.

Já verifiquei todas as ligações com a tabela e está tudo correto...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei ao certo o porque disso acontecer mais para repara basta apagar a `TFDtabel` e o `DataSource` no Delphi e reponha novos e faça todas as ligações com o Banco de dados e pronto ele ira funcionar perfeitamente...